# Check constraint on table in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I want to create a check constraint on a table using liquibase, this is the check constaint :

```
alter table userprefs add constraint chk_null CHECK (updatedate IS NOT NULL OR updateuser IS NOT NULL);
```

I googled about it but all I can find is how to create the check constraint on a column.

How this is can be done on liquibase ?

Answer (score 4):

Liquibase does not support check constraints "natively". You need to put that into a `<sql>` tag:

```
<changeSet author="ichigo" id="1">
  <sql>
     alter table userprefs add constraint chk_null 
        CHECK (updatedate IS NOT NULL OR updateuser IS NOT NULL);
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Hopefully in version 4.x it will be supported https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/374/files